# Are service callbacks not reentrant in practice?

Tags: android, android-service, reentrancy

I am reading "Android programming" by Erik Hellman, and after several "warnings" :-) that service is running in the main activity UI thread I started to wonder if the callbacks are also run in the main thread until I found the statement they are.

This leads me to the conclusion that in practice service callbacks are not reentrant, because if they were it would mean they run concurrently and this would mean one of calls is running outside UI thread.

So for example -- I request updates about GPS location in service and I process each update for a looong time. Will Android queue the updates for me just to make sure my callback is executed in the main thread?

Or did I miss something (most likely :-D)?

*Depending on the callback mechanism and concurrency I write my code differently, but in order to do this I would like to know what guarantee do I have.*

Comment: you mean `LocationManager#requestLocationUpdate(String, LocationListener, Lopper)` ?

Comment: @pskink, yes, as **an example** (the listener would be the service).

Comment: so you have the `Looper`: *"a Looper object whose message queue will be used to implement the callback mechanism, or null to make callbacks on the calling thread"*

Comment: i made a typo: it should be `requestSingleUpdate(String, LocationListener, Lopper)` but `requestLocationUpdates` also has `Looper` param

Comment: @pskink, That is why I emphasized "example", I am asking about service callback model, not this particular GPS one. Besides the rest of the quotation brings me back to my question -- "or null to make callbacks on the calling thread". Calling thread = main thread, so the Android itself queues the callbacks in order to prevent reentrance, correct?

Comment: there is no such thing like `"service callback model"`, here callbacks are done by a class you are using, like `LocationManager` and it is up to that class how it handles its own callbacks

Comment: @pskink, thank you. Could you please post that comment as regular answer (one cannot accept comments, only answers)?